# Folders in Maven parent project

Tags: maven, pom.xml, directory, multi-module

I'm working on a Maven multi-module project, with the following structure:

```
erm-project <pom>
|-- erm-commons <jar>
|-- erm-web <war>
|-- erm-backend <jar>
```

Within the parent project `erm-project` there is a `src/` folder. Is a `src/` folder neccessary for a `pom` type project as there will never be source-code in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. You can download a sample Maven multi-module project from Sonatype [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/mvnex-examples.zip) to see how it is all laid out.